# Android Set min height in constraint layout image view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

How to set min height for an Image view in constraint layout 
I am using glide to load the image from a url and need to set min height for Imageview to show the place holder

```
      <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/banner_image_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/banner_image_view">
                        ....
                    </LinearLayout>
               </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
     </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: If you are using glide than you can directly set placeholder which takes the placeholder height and then when glide loads the image it will take a new image height

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid Hi thanks for the reply I've set the place holder in glide but it is small  a 9 patch image logo. I am using the same for all image  view sizes ... so in this case it would be helpful to fix a minHeight for image view.

Comment: `android:minHeight` works for `ImageView` but is being negated by `android:adjustViewBounds`. Is the issue that you want to nestled a placeholder image in a larger area? Is that why you need `minHeight`?